# Regression Discontinuity by adding a vector of dummy variables..?

Tags: regression, stata

I'm having trouble understanding the following model coded with Stata.

```
reg voteshare milestone bin_10*
reg voteshare milestone bin_20*
reg voteshare milestone bin_50*
```

bin_10* is a vector of binomial variables(bin_101, bin_102, ... ) supposed to account for "regression discontinuity bandwidths". bin_10*, bin_20*, bin_50* are used for different bandwidths (0.1, 0.2, 0.5)

How does adding this variable assume the role of establishing bandwidths in RDD?

**
Substantively, the model aims to explain [US governor vote share changes] per ["milestone"] which is a binomial variable for months when unemployment rate is covered more in the news because the number hit a "milestone" number, which is any solid number change. (e.g. 4.9% ->5.0%, 8.9% -> 9.0% ..., triggered by what is known as the "left digit bias". On the same token, 4.7%->4.8% would not be a milestone, since the increase does not change the left digit.)

By hitting a milestone, the volume of news reports have a discontinuous surge.
Manipulating the bandwidth would be coding different amounts of changes in unemployment as a milestone.
For instance, an unemployment rate change of 4.7%->5.0% would be a milestone with a bandwidth of 0.5, but not with 0.2. With more stringent(smaller) bandwidths, the model is able to more strongly resemble random assignment.